# Use same codes coded for a button in Windows to another button in Android.Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, button, xamarin

Reedit: hey there, here's my situation. I have my portable class library containing my program source codes referenced to the android app. So, I have a button (and other functions not just buttons) in the original project which I want to have on the android app (exactly the same). I have already done alot of research on it but could not find any help except the part where it guides about how to use existing codes on android.

How do I do that?

P.s.: Sorry if its a simple and pointless question. Very new here.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking.  If you are trying to port a Windows app to Android, you will have to rewrite the UI code.  But your UI event handlers can still call the shared code that exists in your PCL.

Comment: how do i call the shared codes from my portable class library? and are the codes of the button in Windows and Android (both in c#) the same? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: no, the UI layer for Windows and Android is completely different.  And your PCL **IS** your shared code

Comment: how do I apply my shared codes from my PCL to the android app when i want them?

Comment: you create a reference to the class in your PCL and call it's methods.  This is basic C# - you use the code in the PCL like you would in any other library

Comment: thanks, i will try it later.

Comment: im sorry but i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/csharp

Comment: thanks for the site, and merry chrismas!